# What happens if stock purchased on margin plummets below what I have in the brokerage?

Tags: stocks, margin

Lets say I have $5k in my brokerage account and I buy a 100 shares of $50 stock on a 4:1 margin. So I put up $1,250 leaving $3750 in the brokerage. 5 minutes later the stock plunges to $4/share and I am down $4600, which I can't cover in the brokerage. What happens? Can I be in debt now to the brokerage? Or will they automatically liquidate my position?

Comment: You are not on margin when you have full $5k of cash in the account to begin with.

Comment: Please add a country tag. U.S. Initial margins are higher than 25%

Comment: I guess the point of my question (math aside) is: if you enter a high leverage trade and it reverses below what you can cover in the account, can you then go into debt? Is it possible to lose 10s of thousands of dollars?

Answer (score 3):

If the price had dropped to $4 from $50, and you had $5000 to start with on your account, you will be left with $400 in your account if you closed the position now. So you would not be in debt if this was the only possition you had open.

Comment: Answer what is asked by the OP and not what he should do, which can be added as an advice/recommendation.

Comment: Problem is OPs math is wrong, he's 100%, not a margined purchase.

Comment: @DumbCoder, you really have a problem reading don't you. Since the OP already has $5000 in his account, if that is the only position that he opens and then after price dropping he liquidates that position he will not owe any money. I have stated the facts not given any recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

Different brokerages have different house rules for margin requirements and margin calls.  You will likely get a margin call giving you a small amount of time to deposit the required funds to bring your account balance up to the required margin requirements.  In reality, a stock that falls from $50 to $4 in a short period will probably become unmarginable.  In short, yes, you will owe the broker for the loss.